# CosmosDB encryption at rest

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-cosmosdb

We have documentDB database with encrypted data. All encryption and decryption are handled on client side. This database was created when there was no support of rest encryption in documentDB. I saw that new rest encryption support in documentDB is HIPAA compliant. It is mentioned in document that it is by default on and there is no user control on that. How can I use this feature in my existing database? Will it help me to get rid of my client side encryption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cosmos DB's encryption-at-rest is not accessible from your application; it's done transparently to you. If you use client-side encryption, you don't need to change it; data will still be encrypted from Cosmos DB's standpoint during writes, and decrypted when read.

Only you can decide whether you need to encrypt client-side, based on your corp policies, customer agreeements, etc. Also keep in mind: all traffic is SSL-based; there's no option for in-the-clear data transport.

Comment: So, will it work like double encryption where we have first encryption on client side with our own key and encryption at rest where Microsoft manages all encryption related things. do the data decrypt as I read document via portal? Is this rest encryption feature automatically available to my older documentDB database?

Comment: Correct - app-level encryption and Cosmos DB service-level encryption are independent. And service-level encryption applies to *all* Cosmos DB databases, including ones existing prior to the feature being rolled out. The portal has no knowledge of service-level encryption; it's just running your queries.

Comment: Thanks David, it helped me understand encryption at rest for cosmosDB more.